# Roll a fair dice until you get 6 . Obtain probability of getting 5 exactly 4 times

Tags: probability-theory

Alice continually rolls a fair 6−sided die until he obtains his first 6. Compute the probability that Alice obtains the value 5 exactly four times before he stops rolling

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question and edit your question in accordance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you compute the probability of hitting 5 before 6. If we denote this probability as $ p $ then it satisfies
$$  p = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{4}{6}p \implies p = \frac{1}{2} $$
Then it becomes fairly simple to compute the probability of hitting 5 four times before 6, which is just
$$ p^4 = \frac{1}{2^4} $$
After obtaining four 5s before any 6, we now need to compute the probability of hitting 6 before 5, which by symmetry is just $ \frac{1}{2} $, thus the probability of hitting 5 exactly 4 times before stopping (hitting 6) is
$$ \frac{1}{2^4} \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} = \cfrac{1}{32} = 0.03125 $$

Comment: Right. In other words, since all outcomes except 5 and 6 are irrelevant, it's just like tossing a coin and asking for the probability that it comes up heads for the first time on the fifth try.

Comment: Yup, that's another way to think about it.